# How do convert a flat structure to a nested using ES6 filter and map

Tags: javascript

I have played around with ES6 filter and map functions trying to convert a flat data structure to a nested structure, I manage to get the desired result but the solution feels very ugly. How can I improve it to avoid using multiple forEach loops?

Nested structure (the result I'm looking for)

```
[
    {
        instance: "EU1",
        testResults:
        [
            {
                label: "PDP",
                success: 10,
                total: 15,
                locales:
                [
                    {
                        locale: "sv_SE",
                        success: 4,
                        total: 5
                    },
                    {
                        locale: "da_DK",
                        success: 3,
                        total: 5
                    },
                    {
                        locale: "no_NO",
                        success: 3,
                        total: 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "PLP",
                success: 12,
                total: 15,
                locales:
                [
                    {
                        locale: "sv_SE",
                        success: 4,
                        total: 5
                    },
                    {
                        locale: "da_DK",
                        success: 4,
                        total: 5
                    },
                    {
                        locale: "no_NO",
                        success: 4,
                        total: 5
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        instance: "EU2",
        testResults:
        [
            {
                label: "PDP",
                success: 12,
                total: 15,
                locales:
                [
                    {
                        locale: "nl_NL",
                        success: 4,
                        total: 5
                    },
                    {
                        locale: "de_DE",
                        success: 4,
                        total: 5
                    },
                    {
                        locale: "de_AT",
                        success: 4,
                        total: 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "PLP",
                success: 14,
                total: 15,
                locales:
                [
                    {
                        locale: "nl_NL",
                        success: 5,
                        total: 5
                    },
                    {
                        locale: "de_DE",
                        success: 5,
                        total: 5
                    },
                    {
                        locale: "de_AT",
                        success: 4,
                        total: 5
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is what I have gotten so far, but can't wrap my head around how to do it in a better way not iterating everything multiple times.

```js
// Flat data structure
const flatData = [
    {
        instance: 'EU1',
        label: 'PDP',
        locale: 'sv_SE',
        success: 4,
        failed: 1,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU1',
        label: 'PDP',
        locale: 'da_DK',
        success: 3,
        failed: 2,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU1',
        label: 'PDP',
        locale: 'no_NO',
        success: 3,
        failed: 2,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU1',
        label: 'PLP',
        locale: 'sv_SE',
        success: 4,
        failed: 1,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU1',
        label: 'PLP',
        locale: 'da_DK',
        success: 4,
        failed: 1,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU1',
        label: 'PLP',
        locale: 'no_NO',
        success: 4,
        failed: 1,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU2',
        label: 'PDP',
        locale: 'nl_NL',
        success: 4,
        failed: 1,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU2',
        label: 'PDP',
        locale: 'de_DE',
        success: 4,
        failed: 1,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU2',
        label: 'PDP',
        locale: 'de_AT',
        success: 4,
        failed: 1,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU2',
        label: 'PLP',
        locale: 'nl_NL',
        success: 5,
        failed: 0,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU2',
        label: 'PLP',
        locale: 'de_DE',
        success: 5,
        failed: 0,
        skipped: 0
    },
    {
        instance: 'EU2',
        label: 'PLP',
        locale: 'de_AT',
        success: 4,
        failed: 1,
        skipped: 0
    }
];

function convertData(data) {
    let results = [];
    if (data && data.length) {
        const labelNames = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.label))];
        const instanceNames = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.instance))];

        let instances = [];
        instanceNames.forEach(instanceName => {
            instances.push({
                instance: instanceName,
                labels: data.filter(({instance}) => instance === instanceName)
                    .map(item => ({
                        label: item.label,
                        locale: item.locale,
                        success: item.success,
                        total: item.success + item.failed + item.skipped
                    }))
            });
        });

        let labels = [];
        instances.forEach(instance => {
            const instanceName = instance.instance;
            labelNames.forEach(labelName => {
                labels.push({
                    instance: instanceName,
                    label: labelName,
                    locales: getByLabel(instance, labelName),
                    success: getSum(instance, labelName, 'success'),
                    total: getSum(instance, labelName, 'total')
                });
            });
            results.push({
                instance: instanceName,
                labels: labels.filter((labelObj) => labelObj.instance === instanceName)
                    .map(item => ({
                        label: item.label,
                        locales: item.locales,
                        success: item.success,
                        total: item.total
                    }))
            });
        });
    }
    return results;
}

function getByLabel(instance, value) {
    let results = [];
    results.push(
        instance.labels.filter(({label}) => label === value)
            .map(item => ({
                locale: item.locale,
                success: item.success,
                total: item.total
            }))
    );
    return results;
}

function getSum(instance, value, key) {
    let total = 0;
    instance.labels.forEach(item => {
        if (item.label === value) {
            total += item[key];
        }
    });
    return total;
}

console.log(convertData(flatData));
```

Comment: I cant recreate the desired result, since in the (flat) data you've given us we miss some data. Like "Passed"

Comment: My bad, wasn't clear enough, passed is the same as success, I have changed it now. On that note, total = success + failed + skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an approach without filtering, but respecting the levels of outer and inner groups.

```js
const
    data = [{ instance: 'EU1', label: 'PDP', locale: 'sv_SE', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PDP', locale: 'da_DK', success: 3, failed: 2, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PDP', locale: 'no_NO', success: 3, failed: 2, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PLP', locale: 'sv_SE', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PLP', locale: 'da_DK', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PLP', locale: 'no_NO', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PDP', locale: 'nl_NL', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PDP', locale: 'de_DE', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PDP', locale: 'de_AT', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PLP', locale: 'nl_NL', success: 5, failed: 0, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PLP', locale: 'de_DE', success: 5, failed: 0, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PLP', locale: 'de_AT', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { instance, label, locale, success: passed, failed, skipped }) => {
        var outer = r.find(q => q.instance === instance);
        if (!outer) r.push(outer = { instance, testResults: [] });
        var inner = outer.testResults.find(q => q.label === label);
        if (!inner) outer.testResults.push(inner = { label, passed: 0, total: 0, locales: [] });
        inner.locales.push({ locale, passed, total: passed + failed + skipped });
        inner.passed += passed;
        inner.total += passed + failed + skipped;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I will have a look at it, thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

I took an approach similar to Nina, but I used direct key-accessors rather than using array `find`/`push` methods. Personal preference, I guess.

The output is slightly different from what you asked. I have added keys where you did not have them. I think you could remove the keys pretty easily, but I think you can foreach the data the same as without them? I'm more into PHP than js, so I'll leave that up to you.

This one appears to be [more performant](http://jsben.ch/tH8J3)

```js
const flat = [ { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PDP', locale: 'sv_SE', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PDP', locale: 'da_DK', success: 3, failed: 2, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PDP', locale: 'no_NO', success: 3, failed: 2, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PLP', locale: 'sv_SE', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PLP', locale: 'da_DK', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU1', label: 'PLP', locale: 'no_NO', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PDP', locale: 'nl_NL', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PDP', locale: 'de_DE', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PDP', locale: 'de_AT', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PLP', locale: 'nl_NL', success: 5, failed: 0, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PLP', locale: 'de_DE', success: 5, failed: 0, skipped: 0 }, { instance: 'EU2', label: 'PLP', locale: 'de_AT', success: 4, failed: 1, skipped: 0 } ];

const output = {};
for (let i=0;i<flat.length;i++){
    const entry = flat[i];
    const instTest = output[entry.instance] || {instance:entry.instance,testResults:{}};
    const labelTotals  = instTest.testResults[entry.label] || {label:entry.label, total:0, success:0,locales:{}};
        labelTotals.success += entry.success;
        labelTotals.total += entry.failed + entry.success + entry.skipped;
    const localeTotal = labelTotals.locales[entry.locale] || {success:0,total:0,locale:entry.locale};
        localeTotal.success += entry.success;
        localeTotal.total += entry.success + entry.failed + entry.skipped;
    
    labelTotals.locales[entry.locale] = localeTotal;
    instTest.testResults[entry.label] = labelTotals;
    output[entry.instance] = instTest;
    
}

//console.log(output);
//console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
document.getElementById("nest-output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output,null,4);
```

```html
<pre id="nest-output">

</pre>
```